# How to update version of v8 (Javascript) is installed with my NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, v8

Need to upgrade only Javascript engine version only to 6.x from 3.x. Is it possible without upgrading nodejs version? Current node version is 0.12.x

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: @torazaburo do you have a source or explanation as per why you say it's impossible ? (That would make a good answer)

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need to do this?

Comment: [Node 0.12.x reached end-of-life 1.5 years ago.](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#end-of-life-releases) Why do you need to continue using an unsupported version of Node?

Comment: The engine version is burned into each node version. One of the primary features of each new node version is a new version of the engine. Asking to change the version is roughly like asking to put a Rolls-Royce jet engine into your volkswagen bug. You can't do it. If you could, then it would probably break whatever you were trying to accomplish by staying with the obsolete node version anyway, which was what exactly?

Comment: Need to add a plugin support that runs on Node 7.X to a Node 0.12.x project. Its complicated to update existing project to latest version

Comment: @SharavanakumaarMurugesan Maybe you could make it work with some new application with Node 7+ that wraps the old one. Unfortunately, keeping an old app with unmaintained engine and libraries will cause you this kind of problems each time you want to add something new :/ . Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Usually, I would recommend using [`udpate-v8`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/update-v8)

```
npm install -g update-v8
```

However, if you use Node.js 0.x, it will not be compatible, as it [requires Node.js 7.6.0 or higher.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/update-v8#installation)

---

Do you realize that you are at least 8 major versions behind the latest version of Node.js? This a huge security risk, to say the least.

You will also get a lost of bug fixes and performance improvement.

You are not explaining while you are staying with this old version. To me, this does not sound like a sane idea.

---

Probably V8 version 6.x is **not** compatible with node v0.12, though I don't find a suitable citation for that.

Version 5.4 of V8 was introduced in version 7 of Node.js (see for instance [this blog infoQ post](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/11/nodejs-v7) ).

It's not telling it's incompatible, but knowing all the changes that happened since the early releases of Node, in EcmaScript / JS and other related standards, I'd rather work towards upgrading node/npm as a priority if I were you.